# Parse JSON array to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need to parse my JSON array to object in Angular, If I am correct but got no idea how to do that. I have read a few posts, and there many on the subject but for some reason I can not get it right.

Link to my JSON: http://wingfield.vmgdemo.co.za/webapi/view_stock_complete

//JS

```
app.controller('showRoom', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://wingfield.vmgdemo.co.za/webapi/view_stock_complete').
    then(function(response) {
        $scope.view_stock_complete = response.data;
    });
});
```

//HTML

```
 <div class="container" ng-controller="showRoom">
<div><span>Variant: {{view_stock_complete.stock_id}}</span></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the browser's JavaScript console? Have you enabled CORS on the server?

Comment: Before there was no errors, I dont have access to the server, I was supplied with the link to my JSON. After applying the suggested change I got the following error:
angular.js:13920SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    
at main.js:45
    at angular.js:16383
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17682)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:17495)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:17790)
    at l (angular.js:11831)
    at J (angular.js:12033)
    at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (angular.js:11966)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is an array, so you'll need to loop over them using `ng-repeat`, or access the first entry using `view_stock_complete[0]`

```js
(function(){
  'use strict';
  
  angular.module('test', [])
    .controller('TestController', TestController);
  
  TestController.$inject = ['$http'];
  
  function TestController($http) {
    var vm = this;
    
    vm.data = [];
    $http.get('http://wingfield.vmgdemo.co.za/webapi/view_stock_complete').then(function(response){
      vm.data = response.data;
    })
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='TestController as tc'>
  <div ng-show="tc.data.length == 0">loading...</div>
  <div ng-repeat="car in tc.data">
    {{$index + 1}}. {{car.make}} {{car.series}}
  </div>
</div>
```